# How to display group by data in jtable in java swing?

Tags: sql, database, swing, jtable

I want to display data in GroupWise, there are this type of field in java swing jtable as shown in picture.

How to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First You should create a `Map<String,java.util.List<Product>> categuryProductMap = new HashMap<String, List<Product>>();`. the first argument
    refers to your categuryName and the second argument is a list of
    product name in coresponding categury.

Then With for statement add first the categury then the list of product to your table model:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, java.util.List<Product>> entry : categuryProductMap.entrySet()) {
    String yourCateguryName = entry.getKey();
    tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{"", "", yourCateguryName, "", "", ""});
    for (Product productNameList : entry.getValue()) {
        String yourProductName = Product.getName();
        Object[] rowForProductName = new Object[]{"", "", yourProductName, "", "", ""};
        tableModel.addRow(rowForProductName);
    }
}
```

i hope this can help little bit.