# how to display group by data in jtabel in java swing?

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing

I have to face one problem I want To display Data in GroupWise
there Are this type of field in java swing jtable.

DataBase Table is :

**1] category**

- categoryID     int
- categoryName   var

**2] product**

- productID     int
- productName   var
- qty           float
- categoryId    int   ref of category[**categoryid**]

Now Display group by query data in jTable java Swing that type format

---

```
cat.Id | cat.Name | prod.Id | Prod.Name | qty | sub Tot | Tot Qty
1      | Mobile _____________________________________   |20
```

- 1    Nokia 5233 [10]
- 2    Nokia Lumiya 510 [10]

---

```
2      |  Pen Drive__________________________________   |50
```

- 1    PNY [20]
- 2    HP  [20]
- 3    Sony [10]

### Total Quantity is_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**_70

Comment: Same question asked by another user http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265763/how-to-display-group-by-data-in-jtable-in-java-swing

Comment: You could take a look at the JXTreeTable from SwingLabs

Answer (score 2):

You can try the EnvelopeTableModel http://java-sl.com/envelope.html
Just load your data and create wrapping model based on the initial one with grouped columns